# Passing two arguments to the function inside of array_map

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I'm working parsing a CSV files, big CSV files and I need to parse a second argument to the str_getcsv function (delimiter), but I honestly have no idea how...

I tried to bypass the array map function, but the php throws an error at me, that allowed memory size was exceeded. I also tried array_walk, but I got the same result.

Here is what the function looks like, right now...

```
function parseIt($file)
{
    $file = file($file);
    // foreach ($file as $key => $value)
    // {
    //     $rows[] = str_getcsv($value, ';');
    //     unset($file[$key]);
    // }
    // array_walk($file, function(&$item)
    // {
    //     $item = str_getcsv($item, ';');
    // });

    // exit();
    return array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
}
```

So, right now, I am trying to figure out how to pass second parameter to str_getcsv through array_map...

Comment: `$delimiter = ';'; return array_map(function ($value) use ($delimiter) return str_getcsv($value, $delimiter); }, file($file));`

Comment: But if you're working with large csv files, then this approach to loading the entire file into memory could be a bad idea

Comment: I'm not shure that this solves the memory problem

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right. It does not work and it is a bad idea... loading the whole file, that is.

Comment: @splash58 No, sadly, it does not help. I guess I will have to refactor and load just chunk and then loop through it... any ideas how to go about that? is there a function that will let me grab just 10000 lines or something like that, or should I load the whole file grab 10000 lines and then unset it?

Comment: Easiest to read a line at a time using fgetcsv() to read and parse in a single statement

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, this seems to be working quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set delimiter in array_map but:

```
<?php

$string = [
    "this;is;a;string;aaa",
    "this2;is;a;string;aaa",
    "this3;is;a;string;aaa",
    "this4;is;a;string;aaa",
];

$output = array_map('str_getcsv', $string, [";", ";", ";", ";", ]);
```

in `[";"]` You must put as many delimiters as rows in input array like in eg.

Other parameters from `str_getcsv` can be done same way.

Comment: While this answer does not solve my problem, cause of the memory, it is definitely right answer considering the question, so +1. :)